# Xcode 5.0 quit unexpetedly while using the automator plug-in

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, xcode5.0.1

i open my project on xcode 5 but everytime it crashes, i am to much worried about that behaviour of xcode. it give me error "Xcode 5.0 quit unexpetedly while using the automator plug-in" kindly help me to find solution of this error. i did completely remove xcode and after that install again but it give same error when i open my project.

Comment: Shauket sahib as Sandeep sugested below, un install it and download/update to latest version. I hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: Try Xcode 5.1 it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved it by myself, just reinstall mavericks again it solve my problem at last.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Xcode completely and then reinstalled it. To uninstall developer tools/Xcode type in the following command in the terminal.

sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

Answer (score 0):

You can try some hints:
1)Download from App store after uninstall
2)upgrade Mac OSx
3)install the simulators path >Xcode menu>preferences>downloads>components

Comment: can u attach the screen shot?
also try "clean my mac" to uninstall

Comment: clean my mac is an application for mac OSx.                             http://macpaw.com/cleanmymac Download from here